# Do we need both "scope" and "off-topic" tags on meta?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, meta

I've noticed we have both [scope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and [off-topic](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) tagged questions in `meta.space.se`. Do we really need both of them? I prefer the [scope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) tag, and I think we could make [off-topic](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) as [one of its synonyms](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/scope/synonyms). Also, [scope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) looks a lot better (less ambiguous, or even confusing) in the list of questions and most active tags of members in the [users lists](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/users). What do you say?

Comment: This was resolved by making off-topic a synonym of scope, despite the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both tags are used on meta.stackoverflow and a few questions **do** fit better with [off-topic](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) than with [scope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope). E.g., asking how a specific off-topic question could be fixed should probably **not** be tagged with [scope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) but would be reasonable to tag with [off-topic](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-topic).

[scope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) questions would include "Is this on-topic?"; [off-topic](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) questions might concern how off-topic questions should be handled. In this scheme, [scope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) questions would deal with **what** is off-topic and [off-topic](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) questions would deal with **how to deal with** questions that have been determined to be out-of-scope.

I realize that expecting such a careful distinction in tagging may be unreasonable (even on meta), but I think that if the main meta site considers the distinction useful it is likely that the distinction **is** useful.

(Interestingly, a few days ago I was thinking of bringing up this very issue, which is why I learned that meta.stackoverflow has such tags.)